# Nested Foreach Loop showing - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have an array with several data.Now i want to retrieve data from it.
This array is stored in `$restaurant_menus`

### Array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [menu_group_name] => Soup
        [menu_group_cover_photo] => Array
            (
                [0] => 430
                [1] => 431
            )

        [menu_group_single_menu] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [single_menu_name] => Miryala Rasam
                        [single_menu_desc] => Pepper Rasam Masala Soup
                        [_price] => 7.99
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [single_menu_name] => Mokkajonna Shorba
                        [single_menu_desc] => Thick sweet corn soup
                        [_price] => 8.99
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I want to show Restaurant menu from it.Menu has a group like `soup` .there is several kinds of soups.So i want to get info like this:

### ---------------------

```
-- Soup
-- Cover Photo
 |----- Single menu -- Price
 |---------------------------------
 |----- Miryala Rasam ---7.99
 |----- Mokkajonna Shorba --- 8.99
```

etc

### -------------------

### I have been using this codes

```
foreach ($restaurant_menus as $restaurant_menu_names) {
    array_shift($restaurant_menu_names);
    foreach ($restaurant_menu_names as $restaurant_menu_name) {
        foreach ($restaurant_menu_name as $restaurant_menu_items) {
            foreach ($restaurant_menu_items as $restaurant_menu_item) {
                print_r($restaurant_menu_item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But error is showing : `Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
its happeing for 3rd foreach loop when using `$restaurant_menu_items` as argument

Comment: Use is_array($restaurant_menus) at each step before calling it inside foreach(). It happens because foreach expects a array as parameter adn not string

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that at each stage you are dealing with an array before trying to access and process it's members - and to do so use `is_array` like this.

```
$menus = $restaurant_menus;

if( is_array( $menus ) && !empty( $menus ) ){
    foreach( $menus as $names ) {

        array_shift( $names );

        if( is_array( $names ) && !empty( $names ) ){
            foreach( $names as $menu ) {

                if( is_array( $menu ) && !empty( $menu ) ){
                    foreach( $menu as $items ) {

                        if( is_array( $items )  && !empty( $items ) ){
                            foreach( $items as $item ) {

                                print_r( $item );

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
$menus=array(
    array(
        'menu_group_name'=>'soup',
        'menu_group_cover_photo'=>array('430','431'),
        'menu_group_single_menu'=>array(
                array(
                        'single_menu_name'=>'Miryala Rasam',
                        'single_menu_desc'=>'Pepper Rasam Masala Soup',
                        '_price'=>7.99
                    ),
                    array(
                        'single_menu_name'=>'Mokkajonna Shorba',
                        'single_menu_desc'=>'Thick sweet corn soup',
                        '_price'=>8.99
                    )
            )
        )
);
if( is_array( $menus ) && !empty( $menus ) ){
    foreach( $menus as $names ) {

        array_shift( $names );

        if( is_array( $names ) && !empty( $names ) ){
            foreach( $names as $menu ) {

                if( is_array( $menu ) && !empty( $menu ) ){
                    foreach( $menu as $items ) {

                        if( is_array( $items )  && !empty( $items ) ){
                            foreach( $items as $item ) {

                                print_r( $item );

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
    output:
    -------
    Miryala Rasam
    Pepper Rasam Masala Soup
    7.99
    Mokkajonna Shorba
    Thick sweet corn soup
    8.99
*/
```

Comment: same problem yet :(